# Отключение множественного нажатия клавиш PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, keypressevent

При зажатии клавиши происходит постоянная её активация, то есть зажав одну букву она продолжает печататься.

Мне нужно чтобы обрабатывался только первый сигнал.

Пробовал в `keyPressEvent` вызывать базовый обработчик и делать `return`, но без изменений. Больше идей нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bool QKeyEvent::**isAutoRepeat**() const
>
> Возвращает `True`, если это событие происходит от автоматически повторяющегося ключа; возвращает `False`, если это происходит при первом нажатии клавиши.
>
> Обратите внимание, что если событие представляет собой сжатое событие с несколькими клавишами, которое частично связано с автоповтором, эта функция может возвращать либо `True`, либо `False` неопределенно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('прога')

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if not event.isAutoRepeat(): 
            print('>>> нажато', event.text())    
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        
    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if not event.isAutoRepeat():
            print('    отжато <<<<<<', event.text()) 
        super().keyReleaseEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]